# scriptaculous drop down menu not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scriptaculous, doctype

I'm using the dropdown menu from http://www.wappler.eu/swdropdownmenu/ and it works fine in all browsers except IE.. the demo on the website works in IE, and the only thing i've changed is the styling.. mine is at http://www.futureworkinstitute.com/2010/ - at first i thought it might have been a conflict between scriptaculous/prototype/jquery, but even after removing other JS, it still doesnt work.

Comment: Looks like a few things are missing. The first level li's need position: relative; Edit: No looks like it works without on their site. But the linked css files on their site has a few extra spaces, maybe that will be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not included a [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) on your website.

With few exceptions, the first line of *every new page* you create should be this, the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Because you haven't included a doctype, your page is rendering in [**Quirks mode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in IE8:

> Quirks mode is a rendering mode used
>   by some web browsers for the sake of
>   maintaining backward compatibility
>   with web pages designed for older
>   browsers or coded without standards
>   conformance.

If you add in that magical doctype line, your drop down works in IE8 and IE7.

I did not notice any significant unpleasant side effects by adding in the doctype, but after adding it, you should test your entire site in every browser you care about to make sure your site still works properly.